# Load a usb driver that has been already inserted in the kernel

Tags: linux, bash, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

I have a usb kernel module that needs to be loaded after it has been insmoded without waiting for re-enumeration

The uses case is something like this
 - Build and insmod the kernel module.
 - The user has the usb devices plugged in, so he/she expects the device to work
  -The driver is present(modprobe show is) but not loaded, thus the usb device does not work

Is there  a way I can force the kernel to reenumarate a given device, I am currently looking at libusb,it seems like the accomplish something similar by issuing an IOCTL.

Comment: Perhaps it's your use of 'load' that is confusing the issue. Running insmod loads a kernel module. If a module shows up with lsmod, it has been loaded. Is the module not detecting the USB device the problem you need help solving?

Comment: no my module is detecting the USB device, but for it to appear in lsmod I need to unplug and plug it back in. Of course this only happens once, right after the driver has been insmoded.

Answer (score 0):

I am a little confused on exactly what you are asking.

Your device's driver should support the "probe" call. When a new device is plugged in, the lower-level USB drivers will detect and enumerate the device(s). After finding each device, it will call the probe functions of all registered USB drivers, passing a reference of the newly found device. This gives each driver the opportunity to "claim" the device as it's own, if it deems it should be used to drive the device.

This enumeration will automatically happen when the devices are plugged in - or (simply speaking) when a new USB module is loaded and registered.

Comment: Suppose no currently-loaded driver claims the device.   If a new USB driver later registers with the system, will it automatically get a shot at claiming the device?

Comment: Yes, absolutely - It sends "polls" for unclaimed devices when new USB drivers are registered.

Comment: hmm.. interesting I am not seeing that.. there could be a bug in my driver.

Comment: after experiment a little bit, it seems like the probe function is not getting called after the driver gets inserted, I wonder if the usb device is already bound to some other driver

Comment: Let me dig around and see if I have some old code I can look at. I've done this a million times - it's just been a few years. I have some nagging doubt that there may be another mechanism involved here too.. :-O

Comment: Do this: Put some debug in the PROBE function to tell you when it's getting called - and with what device. See if it's called when a device is connected - see if it's called when the module is loaded.

Comment: Hi Brad, thanks for the sugestion, I did have those debug messages in place, it turns out that the probe function does get called and the driver gets loaded, thus that is not source of the problem. I am using dkms to install my driver, but it seems like the line 'dkms install ....' is not loading the module, only inserting it. Any idea how I can make dkms install load the module as well, I believe the nvida drivers do something similar, I 'll take a look at them.

Comment: The "normal" way it's done - is to put entiries into struct usb_device_id table - with the vendor and device IDs for your devices. Use the macro MODULE_DEVICE_TABLE and it builds a table in compile-time into your module, so when you run "depmod" - these devices get built into /lib/modules/{kernel}/modules.usbmap file - so when these devices are found - the system knows which modules to load to drive it.